# How to link a new post to a new URL (ReactJS + Redux)?

Tags: javascript, html, url, reactjs, redux

I am using Redux + ReactJS at the moment, and creating a discussion forum. I have a functionality, where a user inputs the title and the content of the new post, and once submitted, it will create a new post.

Once the post is clicked, it directs to a new page with the page filled out with the user inputted title and content. I got the functionality down where it creates a new post, but I can't seem to figure how to generate a new page (with the subdirectory of the url dedicated to that newly created post by the user).

Any suggestions or guidance to achieve it via ReactJS + Redux style would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE** 
In my postReducer.js

```
function getId(posts) {
  return posts.reduce((maxId, post) => {
  return Math.max(post.id, maxId)
  }, -1) + 1
}

let postReducer = function(posts = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case 'ADD_POST':
  return [{
    title: action.title,
    detail: action.content,
    id: getId(posts)
  }, ...posts]

default:
  return posts;
  }
}

export default postReducer
```

In my client.js, how can I call on the newly generated 'id' attribute to be used for param of a dynamic route in client.js?

```
let initialState = {
  posts: [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Discussion Board Rules',
    detail: 'Welcome to Discussion Board Section!'
  }]
}

let store = configureStore(initialState)

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          path="/"
          component={App}
        >
            <IndexRoute
              component={MainCard}
            />
            <Route
              component={FirstPage}
              path="Discussion"
            />
       <Route
              component={Post}
              path="/posts/:id" //**Want to call on the newly generated 'id' for here
            />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`react-router`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)?

Comment: @Kujira Yes I have! I used it to navigate around static pages, but can't seem to wrap my head around as to how it would work for pages being created by user. A small example would be really helpful!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you are creating/storing the posts, but once created, you can have a dynamic route that has `param` pointing to some unique attribute of the post. ie: `<Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post} />` and load the post with specific `id` within `Post` component.

Comment: @Kujira I provided snippets of my code to execute your suggestion. How can I call the 'id' attribute within the client.js to create the dynamic path? Thank you Kujira!

Comment: If it's already loaded in the `redux`, then you can do something like: `state.posts.map(post => <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link>` within some container's `render()` function. This will generate links to all the `posts` available. With this attached with above `Route` which catches the `to`s, you can have a page that displays the selected post.

Comment: @Kujira Appreciate the fast response! I am trying but can't seem to wrap my head around what you are suggesting. If you don't mind, could you provide an example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: apologies for late reply, but I've made a working copy [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nnfvy90/2/). `browserHistory` is not working as intended here, but on your main app you'll have to configure it to work, or just replace it with the default `hashHistory` if needed.

Comment: @Kujira Thank you so much! It works out beautifully~ what is this type of language you used? /${post.id} Thanks again Kujira!!

Comment: Glad it helped! Strings wrapped with ```s are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) added from ES6 I believe. It just makes things look cleaner than having variables and strings concatenated with +s.

Comment: @Kujira Thank you so much! One trouble just came up. So say in your example, say the AppContainer and Post are all separate classes, meaning AppContainer.js and Post.js. In that case, how can I pass on the post.title and post.detail to the Post.js so that it can update itself based what's passed on? Thank you again Kujira

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to clarify that. I just simplified Redux's state management by having a single state object. with `mapStateToProps`, you should be able to use necessary part of state from any file/component.

Comment: @Kujira No worries! and sorry but do you mind showing on jsfiddle again? Seem to understand it more by seeing it. I updated what I am achieving here: https://jsfiddle.net/21e14t1p/1/ Thanks Kujira!

Comment: I rather not. If you understand basic usage of redux then you wouldn't have trouble maintaining the state across files. Start by learning redux!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this:

I have an action creator that sends a post request to my API to create a new post. My API saves the new post in MongoDB, which generates an ID. You could also send a unique slug if you want prettier URLs. The API returns the ID of the created post in its response with a 200 status. The ID of the post is then used to redirect to a different component like so:

```
browserHistory.push(`/posts/${response.data.postId}`);
```

The component at /posts/:postId uses another action to send a get request to my API for the post ID from the params in the URL used to access the component. For example:

```
getPost(this.props.params.postId);
```

I use Axios to send my requests and I believe the official recommendation from React is to place actions for AJAX requests in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm going to look into it but haven't touched on MongoDB. I've updated the main post with some code, do you mind giving any guidance on what to revise with what I provided?